# Rails: Eager loading for models three associations away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I want to show a table of all schedules and the associated classes, partners, and locations in the table columns.

```
# view
<% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
  <%= schedule.date.strftime("%d %b %Y") %>
  <%= schedule.klass.name %>
  <%= schedule.partner.company %>
  <%= schedule.partner.city.name %>
  <%= schedule.start_time.strftime("%l:%M%P") %> -
  <%= schedule.end_time.strftime("%l:%M%P") %>
<% end %>

# models
Schedule 
  belongs_to :klass
  belongs_to :partner
Klass
  belongs_to :partner
Partner
  belongs_to :city
  has_many   :klasses
  has_many   :schedules
City
  none

# controller Schedules
@schedules = Schedule.includes(:klass, :partner).order(:date, :start_time, :end_time)
```

Unfortunately when the page loads it runs the `city` queries multiple times.

```
SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules"  ORDER BY "schedules"."date" ASC, "schedules"."start_time" ASC, "schedules"."end_time" ASC
SELECT "klasses".* FROM "klasses" WHERE "klasses"."id" IN (6, 1, 7, 9, 10, 3)
SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" IN (3, 4, 2)
SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
```

I tried this:

```
Schedule.includes(:klass, :partner).includes(:city)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Association named 'city' was not found on Schedule; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I've read the Rails Guide on Active Record Query but I have no idea on how to improve the query. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

`@schedules = Schedule.includes(:klass, partner: :city).order(:date, :start_time, :end_time)`

Result:

```
SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules"  ORDER BY "schedules"."date" ASC, "schedules"."start_time" ASC, "schedules"."end_time" ASC
SELECT "klasses".* FROM "klasses" WHERE "klasses"."id" IN (6, 1, 7, 9, 10, 3)
SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" IN (3, 4, 2)
SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" IN (23, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Schedule 
  belongs_to :klass
  belongs_to :partner
Klass
  has_many   :schedules
  has_many :partners, through: :schedules
Partner
  belongs_to :city
  has_many   :schedules
  has_many   :klasses, through: :schedules

City
  has_many :partners
```

The query should be

```
@schedules = Schedule.includes(:partner => :city).order(:date, :start_time, :end_time).select('partners.*, cities.name')
```